# loop passwd in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, passwd

how can i make a loop for users of server using shell script
i wrote this code ..

```
#!/bin/bash
b=`awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd | sort`
for $b in /home/$b/ /home/$b/ /home/$b/
echo "$b"
done
```

i want to loop all users and show its

the users like in file

```
/etc/passwd
```

like :

```
root,admin,cpanel,adm,mysql,user1,user2,user3,user4,user5
```

i want the output :

```
/home/adm
/home/root
/home/admin
/home/mysql
/home/user1
/home/user2
```

and thanks

Comment: Is your goal to find all the home directories or to print `/home/username`?  For example, in standard unix, root's home directory is usually `/root`, not `/home/root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print `/home/` before each user name:

```
$ awk -F: ' { print "/home/"$1 }' /etc/passwd | sort
/home/avahi
/home/backup
/home/bin
/home/clamav
/home/colord
/home/daemon
[...snip...]
```

If you want actual home directories, you can find them in field 6:

```
$ awk -F: ' { print $6 }' /etc/passwd | sort
/dev/null
/home/john1024
/nonexistent
/root
```

You can also access the sixth field using `cut`:

```
cut -d: -f6 /etc/passwd | sort
```

#### Printing multiple directories

As per the revised question in the comments:

```
$ awk -F: ' { p="/home/"$1; printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n",p"/www",p"/ftp",p"/etc" }' /etc/passwd | sort
/home/avahi/etc
/home/avahi/ftp
/home/avahi/www
/home/backup/etc
/home/backup/ftp
/home/backup/www
[...snip...]
```

Comment: thanks sir so nice 
but i want to test and loop each user of users in all these paths in tha same time 
/home/user1/www
/home/user1/ftp
/home/user1/etc
/home/user2/www
/home/user2/ftp
/home/user2/etc
/home/user3/www
/home/user3/ftp
/home/user3/etc

how can i do that ? and thanks

Comment: @saba I updated the answer to print multiple directories for each user.

Comment: thanks so much mr.john .. you are cool .. thanks .. best regards for you and thanks for stackoverflow.com

Comment: sir john i have a questions please check my questions please